# adding implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2' make implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' underlined in red

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

After creating an application and a project on `Firebase` and downloading `google-service.json` and placing it in the app repository everything is fine until I try to add any firebase service SDK and after syncing I get the following line:

> implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' underlined
> with red and the following error

```
ERROR: Manifest merger failed: Attribute application @ appComponentFactory value = (android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] 
AndroidManifest.xml: 22: 18-91
is also present at [androidx.core: core: 1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml: 22: 18-86 value = (androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
Suggestion: add 'tools: replace = "android: appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml: 5: 5-19: 19 to override.
```

Comment: You should consider migrating your app to AndroidX. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: Yeah the ``android.support`` library is legacy at this point, ``androidx`` is where all the support libraries live now, and you have a conflict with something importing them (maybe the Firebase library). Migrating to AndroidX will save you a ton of headaches in the future, you'll be able to use the current support libraries, and it should be pretty easy!

Answer (score 0):

You have to migrate your project to androidX , Follow these steps :

Refactor -> Refactor this -> Migrate To AndroidX -> ( a message will pop up to ask if you want to back up your project , it is up to you to do that or not ) -> Do Refactor ->
the project will sync and you re good to go .

Comment: if that helps , please upvote the answer so it helps someone else, thank you and happey coding